# site não funciona em versão mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html5, css3

Fiz um site que por sua vez deve ser responsivo ele terá que funcionar em aparelhos portáteis porem utilizei um recurso chamado [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) desse arquivo eu utilizei os seguintes efeitos :

`fadeInDown`,`fadeInUp`,`fadeInLeft` e `fadeInRight`

eles funcionam corretamente em meu site porem  eu fui fazer um teste em meu celular lembrando que estou fazendo um teste localhost sem internet e eles não funcionam  pois o objetivo deste efeito e que as imagens vão aparecendo conforme eu for rolando a página e isso não acontece e preciso fazer um código especifico para mobile ? estou com essa duvida

Comment: Qual celular? Qual navegador para celular?

Comment: "estou fazendo um teste localhost sem internet " e como estás a passar os ficheiros e usar no mobile?

Comment: @Sergio provavelmente acessando o IP da maquina principal, por exemplo eu consigo acessar meu localhost em qualquer dispositivo conectado a minha rede se eu usar o IP correto.

Answer (score 1):

É possível que o seu mobile não tem suporte para essa funcionalidade.

Confere a versão do navegador do mobile se suporta para esses efeitos, avisando que esse efeito é feito pelo CSS `animation-name` e outras funcionalidades.

Segundo o site [caniuse.com#css-animation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro site:

[MDN CSS-Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation-name)

Answer (score 1):

Cara só por desencargo você está usando um library css (animate) que trabalha com propriedade animation do css baseado na regra @keyframe.
Verificar o uso dos prefixos proprietários para Mozilla e a engine Webkit. Digo isso porque não vi seu código para saber como você usou e juntamente com a tabela que o amigo postou para ter certeza onde esse módulo de animação vai funfar.
Abs!